# encodeWithCoder is not called in derived class of the NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, nskeyedarchiver

Basically I am using some open source code called OrderedDictionary that is derived from NSMutableDictionary. Then I want to save the ordered dictionary data to NSUserDefaults by adding encode and decode method to the OrderedDictionary class. However, I realized the encode and decode methods are not being called, as a result, the decoded dictionary is no longer ordered. Below is my code:

```
@interface OrderedDictionary : NSMutableDictionary <NSCopying, NSCoding>
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
    NSMutableArray *array;
}
```

In the implementation file:

```
/**
 * encode the object
 **/
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [super encodeWithCoder:coder];
    [coder encodeObject:dictionary forKey:@"dictionary"];
    [coder encodeObject:array forKey:@"array"];
}

/**
 * decode the object
 */
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        dictionary = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"dictionary"];
        array = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"array"];
    }   
    return self;
}
```

Quick example code for using this:

```
dictionary = [[OrderedDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setObject:@"one" forKey:@"two"];
[dictionary setObject:@"what" forKey:@"what"];
[dictionary setObject:@"7" forKey:@"7"];
NSLog(@"Final contents of the dictionary: %@", dictionary);

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myDictionary"] == nil)
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary] 
                                          forKey:@"myDictionary"];
}
else
{
    NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSData *savedDictionary = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"myDictionary"];

    if (savedDictionary != nil)
    {
        OrderedDictionary *oldData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedDictionary];
        if (oldData != nil) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Final contents of the retrieved: %@", oldData);

        } 
    }
}
```

The thing is, the final retrievedDictionary does NOT have the original data order and the encode and decode methods are not called at all.

Thanks for any help in advance! :)

Comment: I suspect there is no way to fix it, i.e. we may not be able to call child class's encode and decode methods of a NSMutableDictionary....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an NSObject method called `-classForCoder` that you need to override in OrderedDictionary. From the docs:

> classForCoder
>   Overridden by subclasses to substitute a class other than its own during coding.
>
> -(Class)classForCoder
>   Return Value
>   The class to substitute for the receiver's own class during coding.
>
> Discussion
>   This method is invoked by NSCoder. NSObject’s
>   implementation returns the receiver’s class. The private subclasses of
>   a class cluster substitute the name of their public superclass when
>   being archived.

That last line is the key. So, in OrderedDictionary.m:

```
- (Class)classForCoder 
{  
    return [self class]; // Instead of NSMutableDictionary
}
```

Also, if you're not using ARC, make sure you retain the objects coming back from `-decodeObjectForKey`. As rob mayoff mentions below, you shouldn't call `[super initWithCoder:]`  (or `[super encodeWithCoder:'`). I also changed the key strings to avoid collisions.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    if (self != nil)
    {
        dictionary = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"OrderedDictionary_dictionary"] retain];
        array = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"OrderedDictionary_array"] retain];
    }   
    return self;
}
```

Comment: He also needs to avoid calling `[super initWithCoder:]` unless he's also implemented `initWithObjects:forKeys:count:`, or he will crash.  And if he doesn't call `[super initWithCoder:]` then he shouldn't call `[super encodeWithCoder:]` either.

Comment: Thanks for catching that rob. Edited my answer to include it.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen I've tested the changes you made, worked great! Thank you so much! Shouldn't we add this answer to the original OrderedDictionary code? :)

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly creating a new `OrderedDictionary` with the wrong initializer, `initWithDictionary:`. Try this instead:

```
OrderedDictionary *oldData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: savedDictionary];
if (oldData != nil) 
{
    NSLog(@"Final contents of the retrieved: %@", oldData);
}
```

Make sure `initWithDictionary:` expects `OrderedDictionary` as an argument. My guess is that it expects an `NSDictionary`.

Edit: the code to save the defaults should include something like this:

```
OrderedDictionary *myDict = ...;
NSData* data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: myDict];
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setObject: data forKey: @"myDictionary"];
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I just tried your way. The output is still not right, data order is no longer reserved. I've updated my code in this post to reflect the change you made. I think the problem is my encodeWithCoder was not called at all, so that the encode and decode methods in parent class (NSMutableDictionary) was called. However, i dont know how to fix this.

Comment: Make sure you use `NSKeyedArchiver` when saving defaults. Put `NSLog()` in your `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:` to see if they get called and work correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. I think the archiving code I did is the same as yours, just I combined two lines of code into one. It's still not calling the encode and decode methods.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
        setObject: [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary]
        forKey:@"myDictionary"];