# Why is encodeWithCoder not getting called on a subclass of SKNode during application state preservation?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, nscoding, skspritenode, state-restoration

Summary: When I derive a custom class from an `<NSCoding>` parent, I see my `encodeWithCoder` method called during application state preservation.  If I change my parent to `SKNode`, my `encodeWithCoder` method is no longer called.

Details:

My view controller gets encoded during `UIKit` application state preservation.  It encodes a single object of type `MyNode`.

```m
- (void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
  [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

  MyNode *myNode = [[MyNode alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"view controller encoding");
  [coder encodeObject:myNode forKey:@"myNode"];
}
```

`MyNode` is a stripped-down class built for this question.  I'll include the code for completeness, but the encode and decode methods merely call `NSLog` and `super`.

```m
@interface MyParent : NSObject <NSCoding>
@end

@interface MyNode : MyParent
@end
```

```m
@implementation MyParent

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
  NSLog(@"MyParent decoding");
  self = [super init];
  return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
  NSLog(@"MyParent encoding");
}

@end

@implementation MyNode

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
  NSLog(@"MyNode decoding");
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
  return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
  NSLog(@"MyNode encoding");
  [super encodeWithCoder:aCoder];
}

@end
```

When the parent of `MyNode` is `MyParent`, as written above, then I see my logged output during application preservation:

```
2014-05-12 15:22:33.342 Flippy[35091:60b] saving application state
2014-05-12 15:22:33.342 Flippy[35091:60b] view controller encoding
2014-05-12 15:22:33.343 Flippy[35091:60b] MyNode encoding
2014-05-12 15:22:33.343 Flippy[35091:60b] MyParent encoding
```

But when I change the parent of `MyNode` to `SKNode`, then my `encodeWithCoder` implementations are not called:

```
2014-05-12 15:22:57.847 Flippy[35115:60b] saving application state
2014-05-12 15:22:57.848 Flippy[35115:60b] view controller encoding
```

Why not?

Things I have tried:

- Archiving my custom class using my own `NSKeyedArchiver`.  This works as expected.
- Implementing `UIStateRestoring` protocol on my custom class, and registering it with the application with a restoration identifier.  This didn't make much sense to me.
- Messing with `classForCoder`, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004783/encodewithcoder-is-not-called-in-derived-class-of-the-nsmutabledictionary).  But it doesn't sound like it applies, and `classForCoder` is not getting called on my custom class anyway.

(The details of my real-world problem that inspired this test case don't seem relevant.)

Comment: I had answered it was because `SKNode` doesn't implement `NSCoding`. Karl pointed out (correctly): "Good thought, but `SKNode` does implement `NSCoding` (see `SKNode` Class Reference). Also, the way message handling works, even if `MyNode` didn't declare that it conformed to `<NSCode>`, it would still try to handle the `encodeWithCoder` message." I have removed my answer because people might ignore the question since it already has an answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm working on a new app and running into the same problem, and it still boggles me: What is happening in `NSKeyedArchiver encodeObject:forKey:` that can prevent the object's `encodeWithCoder:` method from being called, and what is `SKNode` doing to prevent such a thing? The answer must be in the source code.